# Shift Cable for 1963 Schwinn w/Sturmey Archer Shifter

Tags: shifter, vintage, cable, schwinn

This is the shifter on my 1963-64 Schwinn Racer:

[image]

This is the old cable:

[image]

I'd like to replace the cable and found this:

[image]

It's hard to tell what the cable ends look like inside the packaging but is anyone familiar with this Schwinn part number and if it's compatible with my shifter? I know there are newer style cables with a loop connecting the adjusting nut (ferrule?) to the hub chain, but I'd like to find the older style if possible.

This is my bicycle. There are many others like it, but this one is mine. My bicycle is my best friend. :-)

[image]

Comment: IIRC the first number is the cable length and the second number is the housing length. I would compare those lengths with yours. If the cable length is the same, I would say you are safe to go.

Comment: @P.Barney thanks for the comment! I measured my cable and it is indeed 54". My housing is shorter at only 17" but I'm guessing trimming it down will be no big deal.

Comment: @Anthony I believe vintage sets like that cannot be trimmed. The hub-end tip is integral. That's why modern sets are the way they are, to be trimmed to length.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15288/how-to-replace-a-sturmey-archers-cable

Comment: @NathanKnutson Ah...that makes sense. In that case, I think if I move the chrome bracket on the top tube (see bike picture) 8" towards the seat, I should be able to accommodate the extra housing length. I don't think it'll interfere with the rear brake cable that also runs under the tube, but I'll find out soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information provided by @P.Barney and @NathanKnutson, I realized that while the cable will most likely work in my shifter, the housing is the wrong length for my particular application. Based on the specs of my old cable, I believe the correct cable to be:

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on this. The cable I ordered has a slightly different fitting for the shifter. I haven't tried to fit it yet so I don't know if it will work as it is threaded and the original is more of a slide fit. [Here's a picture of the new fitting](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/screenshot-dump-monosnap/Monosnap_2020-09-17_10-58-11.png)